# Jquery load isn't working when trying load content through a link, redirects instead of updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'd like to change to set the content in a div using a link

My HTML code:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="dashboard.html">dashboard</a>
<a href="basic-info.html">basic-info</a>
<div id="content"></div>


<script src="scripts/links.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS Code:

```
//inside of links.js 
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load("dashboard.html");
});
```

Comment: That should work. Are you clicking on `<a>` to get the content into `div` ?

Comment: My goal was to have links that are clickable: update content when clicked. load() still wasn't working. Now I want load to just update #content using dashboard.html, which is the above. To answer your question - No, b/c I just want the content to load at this point

Comment: *Now I want load to just update #content using dashboard.html* : Then the above should should work. Check the path of `dashboard.html`. Try `/dashboard.html`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an event listener to the links and you also need to prevent the default action as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();//prevents following the link
        $('#content').load( this.href );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking a link which is pointing at another file so the browser is trying to redirect to this file.

You'll need to prevent the default behaviour of the link and use it as a JS trigger to load the content with Ajax.

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');

  $('#content').load(url);
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: How do you just load() the 'dashboard.html' into #content? I just want dashboard.html content to be loaded in #content div